# Fixing Overridden state for features

Tags: features

The feature are coming into override state always. After running 'revert', it goes into default state and everything is fine,however. My client are unable to do the revert every single time its being enabled.
Why is it coming into override state always? There are no changes made... fresh install, enabled and it is in override state. Running diff shows:

```
Component type: fe_block_settings
        ),
        'cascade' => array(
<         'region' => 'page_header',
---
>         'region' => 'sidebar_first',
          'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
<         'weight' => -10,
---
>         'weight' => -1,
        ),
        'seven' => array(
        ),
        'cascade' => array(
>         'region' => 'help',
>         'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
        ),
        ),
        'cascade' => array(
<         'region' => 'sidebar_first',
<         'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
<         'weight' => -11,
        ),
        'seven' => array(
        ),
        'cascade' => array(
>         'region' => 'sidebar_first',
>         'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
<         'weight' => -9,
        ),
        'seven' => array(
        ),
        'cascade' => array(
<         'region' => 'navigation',
---
>         'region' => 'footer',
          'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
<         'weight' => -9,
---
>         'weight' => 10,
        ),
        'seven' => array(
        ),
        'cascade' => array(
<         'region' => 'user_popover',
<         'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
        ),
          'status' => 1,
          'theme' => 'cascade',
<         'weight' => -8,
        ),
        'seven' => array(


Component type: variable
      'api_version' => 1,
      'name' => 'site_name',
<     'value' => 'Cas<strong>ca</strong>de <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>',
---
>     'value' => 'Cascade Site',
```

As you see one is variable 'site_name'. This variable is not changed, so i am coming to conclusion that when enabling the feature it is not setting the variable 'site_name'. Can it be true? if so, why and how to fix? The same seems to be the case with fe_block_settings. I really would appreciate your help as this is becoming the case with many of my features. I would really like become good at troubleshooting and understanding features. Thank You a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if your feature set variables or configurations that are already stored on db, you have to revert it. instead this does not happen for "new" configurations.

Comment: Arrubiu, are you saying that for variables already in db, they aren't being reset with new values on feature enable? this is normal behavior?

Comment: Exactly, I think this is the default beahviour.